# Sorting multiple values of a single key

Tags: sorting, dictionary, distinct-values

I'm really struggling to find a way to organize multiple values inside a single key.

ex: {'A':[(2000,1),(1999,1)]}

I'm trying to cause the values to sort based on the 0 position of each value (2000 and 1999 in this case). Any help to which pieces of code could do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: (2000,1) is not a valid value for an array, maybe you meant [2000,1] or "(2000,1)" If you're trying to find the 0 value, you better do it the first way: [2000,1]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, (2000,1) is a tuple. the full dictionary I'm looking at is this.

d = {("A","MALE"):[ (2000,30,None),(2005,50,None)]}

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you were using javascript, my bad.